# If else condition using BI Publisher RTF

Tags: xslt, rtf

I have a report to create requested by the user, now my problem is I was stuck while creating it in an `RTF` template. Because I have a two columns that contains different value. For example, I have a table that contains a value. Please see below.

```
Item_Number     Discount      Number1       Number2
Item1           500           145           156
```

Then I want in the report that when the discount is greater than 0, it will returned the column `Number1` else `Number2`

I tried `<?xdofx:if DISCOUNT < 0 then ‘Number1’ else 'Number2' end if?>`

but I returned the value of the 3 columns. I tried also to removed the apostrophe but I returned the same value.

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do this in XPATH but in my opinion this kind of logic is much easier to handle at the SQL level.  Is that an option for you?